# How to find the origin of MPI message truncated errors?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, runtime-error, mpi

I am currently having problems with a MPI Application.

I am sporadically receiving MPI errors of the form:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Allreduce: Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Allreduce(1339)...............: MPI_Allreduce(sbuf=0x7ffa87ffcb98, rbuf=0x7ffa87ffcba8, count=2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Allreduce_impl(1180).........: 
MPIR_Allreduce_intra(755).........: 
MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found(129): Message from rank 0 and tag 14 truncated; 384 bytes  received but buffer size is 16
rank 1 in job 1  l1442_42561   caused collective abort of all ranks
exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 9
```

However I do not know at where to look. I know that the error is happening in an Allreduce function call however there are multiple ones.

How do I know which function call produces the error? Simple printf debugging does not help as the function could be called a million times before the error occurs the first time.

It might also not occur at all or immediately after the start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to track down the origin of the error by calling

```
MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN)
```

and then checking the return value of each of the Allreduce functions for not being equal to MPI_SUCCESS. This is a location where an error occurs

Comment: It's obvious that the error is there. The bigger issue is what you were doing wrong at that point. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I was able to figure that out by adding a sleep on error and attaching to the different processes with gdb and then backtracing the calls. It all stemmed from diverging codepaths that assumed the other was following the same path.